# unexpected '!'что с этим делать

Tags: php

Столкнулся с этой прескорбной надписью

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tast\signup.php on line 7

Вот код этой части php данного документа

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));

$password1=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password1']));

$password2=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password2']));
    if(!empty($username) &&  !empty($password1) !empty($password2) && (&password1 == password2)) {
```

Comment: Вы не знаете, как правильно писать выражения внутри `if`?

Comment: `!empty($password1) !empty($password2) ` добавьте какое-либо логическое выражение между данными конструкциями

Comment: && (&password1 == password2)

Answer (score 1):

```
if((!empty($username)) &&  (!empty($password1)) &&(!empty($password2)) && ($password1 == $password2)) {
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: а зачем `!empty()` с скобки пихать?